# How to diff the current file when using GitExtensions

Tags: visual-studio, diff, git-extensions

Is there a way to quickly do a diff the file currently being edited in 
Visual Studio against its version in master? The best I've been able 
to find is to do Git > Commit, and find the file in the list of 
working dir changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the git source control provider extension

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/63a7e40d-4d71-4fbb-a23b-d262124b8f4c/

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged your question with "git extensions" I'll go ahead and assume that you've installed Git Extensions. =)

Having installed Git Extensions you should in Visual Studio now have a new toolbar provided by Git Extensions.

What you also now have available are some new options in a series of context menus. Right click anywhere in a file you're working with in Visual Studio and select "Git: Diff". This will open your diff tool of choice showing you the changes in your working copy compared to the latest known commit in the branch your working in.